# Showing that a function is the restriction of another holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, analytic-continuation

Let $f$ be holomorphic on the annulus $\{z:\;1-\epsilon<|z|<1+\epsilon\}$. Define:
$$\phi:\;D\to\mathbb{C};\quad  \phi(w)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C \frac{f(z)}{z-w}\,\mathrm{d}z$$
where $C$ is the unit circle, $D$ is the open unit disk. I want to show that $\phi$ is the restriction of a holomorphic function defined on  $\{z:\;|z|<1+\epsilon\}$

---

**Work:**

I have proved that $\phi$ is indeed analytic on $D$ via a series expansion & series/integral swap using uniform convergence. I also know that $f$ must have a Laurent series on compact subsets of the annulus, so write: 
$$f(w)=\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty} c_k w^k\;\text{where}\;c_k=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C\frac{f(z)}{z^{k+1}}\mathrm{d}z$$
Then reversing the series expansion I did, I get for $w\in D:$
$$f(w)=\phi(w)+f_{\text{principal}}(w)$$
I'm not really confident about what I'm doing. Am I along the right lines?

Comment: you know the theorem : if $C_1$ and $C_2$ are two closed contours $\subset U$ (some open)  and $C_1$ can be homotopically (continuously) strechted to become $C_2$, then $\int_{C_1} g(z) dz = \int_{C_2} g(z) dz$ whenever $g(z)$ is holomorphic on $U$. this is more or less a direct consequence of the Cauchy integral theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: For $1-\epsilon<r<1+\epsilon$ define $\phi_r(w)$ for $|w|<r$ by $$\phi_r(w)=\frac1{2\pi i}\int_{C_r}\frac{f(z)}{z-w}dz,$$where $C_r$ is the circle $|z|=r$. Show that if $|w|<r_1<r_2$ then $\phi_{r_1}(w)=\phi_{r_2}(w)$.

Comment: Ok thanks. Does this work: consider two contours, each of which is a "half the annulus $r_1<z<r_2$" (each contour is half of both circles, and endpoints of arcs joined up) so that they cancel i.e. adding them is $\int_{C_{r_1}}-\int_{C_{r_2}}$, and then by analyticity (since $w$ is not in the annulus) the integral along both contours is $0$, so $\phi_{r_1}(w)=\phi_{r_2}(w)?$

Comment: That works, with a very rudimentary version of Cauchy's Theorem. The fact that the integral over the two $C_r$ is the same is immediate from a slightly more sophisticated version of $CT$: $C_{r_1}$ and $C_{r_2}$ are homotopic in the annulus.

Comment: Ah right, maybe that will be introduced later in the course - thanks again